# Dimension of the variety of rank 1 decompositions of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, matrix-rank, tensor-rank

Let $A\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and let's consider its decompositions into a sum of rank 1 matrices
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^t A_i,\ \text{rank}(A_i)=1,$$

where $t\geqslant n$. When $t=n$, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition#Generic_identifiability) claims that if we write $A_i=u_iv_i^T$ for some vectors $u_i,v_i\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and collect all the vectors into matrices $U=[u_i]_{i=1}^n,\ V=[u_i]_{i=1}^n$, then for a general matrix $X\in\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{C})$ defining $c_i,d_i\in \mathbb{C}^n$ by $$UX^{-1}=[c_i]_{i=1}^n,\ VX^{T}=[d_i]_{i=1}^n,$$ yields a new decomposition. It refers to Joe Harris' "Algebraic Geometry: A First Course", but I couldn't find this result there. It's also not immediately clear why acting by $X$ like this on a decomposition yields all decompositions.

But I am also interested in the more general question when $t>n$, especially when furthermore $t\geqslant 2n-1$, which is the dimension of the space of rank 1 matrices. What can be said about such decompositions?

Comment: There's no need to say "up to a permutation": one can permute the vectors of $U$ and $V$ in a like fashion by taking $X$ to be a permutation matrix.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh, right! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's show for good measure that given such matrices $U$ and $V$, the matrices $UX^{-1}$ and $VX^T$ (with $X \in GL_t$) yield a valid decomposition. Note that the columns of $U,V$ correspond to a decomposition of $A$ if and only if $UV^T = A$. Thus, it suffices to note that for any $X \in GL_t$, we have
$$
(UX^{-1})(VX^T)^T = UX^{-1}XV^T = UV^T = A.
$$
Now, we wish to show that all such decompositions can be attained in this fashion (i.e. the action of $GL_t$ is transitive). First, note that it suffices to consider the case where $A = I$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix): $A = UV^T$ holds iff $I = (A^{-1}U)V^T$ holds.

So, we are considering all pairs of matrices $U,V \in \Bbb C^{n \times t}$ for which $UV^T = I$. First, we consider only the pairs for which we have
$$
U = U_0 := \pmatrix{I_n & 0}.
$$
Verify that an $n \times t$ matrix $V$ will satisfy $U_0V^T = I$ if and only if $V = \pmatrix{I & W}$, where the matrix $W$ of size $n \times (t-n)$ may be freely chosen.

> **Claim:** The action of $GL_t$ is transitive over all pairs $U,V$ satisfying $UV^T = I_n$ for which $U = U_0$.

*Proof of Claim:* It suffices to show that an arbitrary pair $U_0,V$ lies within the orbit of $U_0,U_0$. As discussed above, it must hold that $V$ has the form $V = \pmatrix{I_n & W}$. Let $X$ be the matrix
$$
X = \pmatrix{I_n & 0\\-W^T & I_{t-n}}.
$$
Verify that this $X$ satisfies $U_0 X^{-1} = U_0$ and $V X^T = U_0$. $\square$

With the claim proved, it suffices to note that for any pair $U,V$ with $UV^T = I_n$, there exist a matrix $X \in GL_t$ such that $UX^{-1} = U_0$. To that end, it suffices to note that $U$ must have linearly independent rows (since it has full row-rank $n$), which means there exists a matrix $X \in GL_t$ whose first $n$ rows are the matrix $U$, which means that this matrix will satisfy $U_0X = U$, and hence $U_0 = UX^{-1}$.

---

Regarding the nature of these decompositions, I suspect that it might be helpful to take an [orbit-stabilizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem) kind of approach. In particular, I suspect that the dimension of the variety of such pairs will be the total dimension of the variety $GL_t$ (namely, $t^2$) minus the dimension of the subgroup of stabilizers of any particular pair $U,V$.

To understand the subgroup of stablizers, it suffices to look at the single pair where $U = V = U_0$, with $U_0$ as defined above. Note that $U_0X^{-1} = U_0$ holds if and only if $X$ has the form
$$
X = \pmatrix{I_n & 0\\X_{21} & X_{22}}.
$$
On the other hand, such a matrix $X$ will satisfy $U_0X^T = U_0$ if and only if it further satisfies
$$
X = \pmatrix{I_n & 0\\0 & X_{22}}.
$$
So, the stablizer subgroup is isomorphic to $GL_{t-n}$, which has dimension $(t-n)^2$. With that, we conclude that the dimension of the variety of pairs $U,V$ satisfying $UV^T = I$ will be
$$
t^2 - (t-n)^2 = n(2t-n).
$$
By the correspondence described above, the same should hold for the set of pairs satisfying $UV^T = A$ for any element $A \in GL_n$.

Comment: +1 Just to amplify the content of your final paragraph(s), if an algebraic group $G$ acts on algebraic variety $X$ then for any $x\in X$ there is an 'orbit scheme' $O_x\subseteq X$. If one wants to avoid fancy language, what this means is that the set $O_x$ (computed in the normal sense of orbits) is a locally closed subset of $X$, so has the structure of a reduced algebraic variety. It is then true that, as you suggest, the dimension of $O_x$ is $\dim(G)-\dim(\mathrm{Stab}(x))$. In particular, if $\dim(X)=\dim(G)-\dim(\mathrm{Stab}(x))$ and $X$ is reduced, then $X=O_x$ as you suggested.

Comment: Oops, I should also say that $X$ is irreducible, so that $X$ is actually integral (else it could be the case just that $X=O_x\sqcup O_y$ where $O_y$ has dimension $0$).

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I appreciate the confirmation of my intuition there; all I was able to say was that this seems like the kind of "trick" that seems like it should work here, but I have some pretty big holes in my understanding of algebraic geometry. I suspect that this is a well known result, could you point me to a reference that discusses this?

Comment: Hey Ben, I wrote the above in haste and made a simple mistake which I am confused how I could've made. Anyways, all one can deduce from the above discussion is that $O_x$ is open. Indeed, think about $\mathrm{GL}_2$ acting on $\mathbb{A}^2$ and the orbit of $(1,1)$--this orbit has the saime dimension as $\mathbb{A}^2$, but is certainly not everything. My apologies!

Comment: That doesn't seem right. If we identify the pair $U = (x_1,x_2), V = (x_3,x_4) \in \Bbb C^{2 \times 1}$ with the point $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \Bbb A^4$ and take $y = (1,0,1,0)$, then $O_y = \{x: x_1x_2 + x_3x_4 = 1\}$, which is clearly a closed, proper subset of $\Bbb A^4$.

Comment: Hey Ben. Can you clarify what your example is in reference to?